# C++ error Expected primary expression before "'" token (using getline on an ifstream?)

Tags: c++

I am getting many errors along the lines of "error: expected primary-expression before ',' token" wherever I am using the getline function in my code.
I looked at some examples of people using getline on ifstreams, and I thought that maybe I had to put "std::" before calling the function (not really sure what that would do though?) but that didn't work either.

Here's the first bit of my code; I'm assuming that whatever error I'm making is the same throughout.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct ListNode{
  string user;
  string salt;
  string encrypted;
  string password;
  ListNode* next;
};


int main(){

  /* Initializes singly linked list to hold user data */
  ListNode *root;
  ListNode *conductor;
  root = new ListNode;
  conductor = root;

  string temp;

  //creates and opens filestream to password file                                                                      
  ifstream psswdFile ("example.txt");

  if(psswdFile.is_open()){
    //we assume there is at least one line, and initialize the head of                                                 
    //the list                                                                                                         
    std::getline(psswdFile&, (conductor->user)&, ':');
    std::getline(psswdFile&, (conductor->salt)&, ':');
    std::getline(psswdFile&, (conductor->encrypted)&);
```

Comment: `std::getline(psswdFile&, (conductor->user)&, ':');`  Can you explain what you're trying to do here?

Comment: you don't need an `&` to pass parameters by reference in C++. Just write `std::getline(pswdFile, [...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have misunderstood the way you pass parameter references to C++ functions. Unlike pointers that usually need you to obtain the address using the `&` operator, functions that take references do not need you to do anything: simply pass an assignable expression:

```
std::getline(psswdFile, conductor->user, ':');
```

The compiler has the forward declaration of your function, so it knows to pass whatever you are passing by reference.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! thanks, I guess I need to reread that chapter!